# What does 'fileprivate' keyword means in Swift?

Tags: swift, private, access-modifiers

I'm starting in swift and opening a project created using swift2 from xcode 8 beta, the `private` modifier were changed to `fileprivate`. what does this keyword means? and how is different from `private` ?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

`fileprivate` is one of the new Swift 3 access modifiers that replaces `private` in its meaning. `fileprivate` defines an entity (class, extension, property, ...) as private to everybody outside the source file it is declared in, but accessible to all entities in that source file.

`private` restricts the entity in the direct enclosing scope.

Comment: what do you mean by "direct enclosing scope"? When would I use just `private` instead of `fileprivate`?

Comment: the enclosing scope is the set of blocks or file in this extend in which an entity is declared, `private` is meant to hide implementation details or keep things hidden that are restricted to the owner while `fileprivate` can be used to share some common functionality between all entities in the same file.

Comment: In swift < 3.0 'private' works like 'fileprivate' in swift 3.0. If you declare in swift 2.3 e.g. two classes with private variables but in the same file they had still access to each of 'private' marked variables.